# Design \chapter*, toc and shorttoc {memoir}

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Documentclass memoir.
Did the design of the head thus:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,small, openany,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{cmap}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{cite,float,textcomp,setspace}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{paratype}

\usepackage{ArtNouv}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\ArtNouvfamily{}}  
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage[pdflatex]{graphicx,xcolor}
\graphicspath{{grafika/}} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\redstar}{$\textcolor[rgb]{.87,0,0}{\bigstar}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-6pt]{79}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,symmetry=v,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-6pt]{79}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{0\p@}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7mm}\noindent\fbox{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
   \framebox[\textwidth-13.0pt][c]{\hspace*
{0.25\parindent}\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase
{\lquercus\redstar\rquercus~~\@chapapp  
\thechapter\hfill#1~~\lquercus\redstar\rquercus}\hspace*
{0.25\parindent}}}
\par\nobreak
\vskip 10\p@}
\makeatother

\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\geometry{left=10mm}
\geometry{right=10mm}
\geometry{top=15mm}
\geometry{bottom=15mm}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{nolistsep} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{\Large\bfseries Подробное содержание}}  
\contentsmargin{0cm} 

\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{8pt}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\normalsize\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}  
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 

\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{3pt}\small\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\small\sffamily\small}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\small\sffamily\small} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\null\hfill\textbf{\Large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\setlength\columnsep{10mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}[
\chapter*{\centering\Large\contentsname   
    \@mkboth{
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]
\@starttoc{toc}
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother  

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\ULdepth = 0.16em 
\usepackage{pdf14}
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\doublehyphendemerits=1000000
\finalhyphendemerits=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\textsection~}
\shorttoc{\centerline{\large{\bfseries{Краткое содержание}}}}{0}

\chapter{С чего начать\ldots} % this \chapter should be \chapter*
\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent =0pt]{B}{э}том документе (my text)

\chapter{Первые блюда}
\noindent                    % minitoc two columns
\makebox[1.01\textwidth]{
{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-7\mboxsep-3\mboxrule\relax}
\centering
\setlength\columnsep{10mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\end{multicols}\\
\phantom{123}\\
\end{minipage}}
}

\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent =0pt]{P}{а}ньше я (my text)
\phantom{\lipsum[1]}
\vspace{-7mm}
\section{1}
\subsection{1.1}
(my text)

\chapter{2} 
\noindent     % minitoc one column 
\makebox[1.01\textwidth]{
{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-7\mboxsep-3\mboxrule\relax}
\centering
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\\
\phantom{123}\\
\end{minipage}}
}

\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent =0pt]{O}{б} этой (my text)
\phantom{\lipsum[5]}
\vspace{-7mm}
\section1 \subsection1 \subsubsection1 (my text)
...
\chapter{10}
\clearpage  
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Result:[image]
How can you make the same design for \chapter*, \shorttoc and \tableofcontents?

P.S. I fixed his post, pointed to the preamble and the structure of the document.

The document is compiled, but how to make a header appearance \chapter*, \shorttoc and \tableofcontents similar to the design of the title \chapter?..

Unfortunately, I'm only a user, not a developer.

Texmaker 5.0.2, TeXLive 2017 (updated 2016), Slackware 14.2.

Comment: Please make your code snippets compilable

Comment: `titlesec` and `memoir`? Really?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I made the design of the Chapter this way (I have cleaned the preamble, so I will give the code completely):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,small,openany,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{cmap}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{cite,float,textcomp,setspace}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{paratype}

\usepackage{ArtNouv}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\ArtNouvfamily{}}  
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage[pdflatex]{graphicx,xcolor}
\graphicspath{{grafika/}} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\redstar}{$\textcolor[rgb]{.87,0,0}{\bigstar}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-6pt]{79}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,symmetry=v,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-6pt]{79}}

\renewcommand{\ornament}{\lquercus\redstar\rquercus}

\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\vspace*{0\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}
    \fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-10pt][c]{
    {\Large\bfseries\ornament\ \ \ 
\chaptername\,\!\thechapter\hfill#1\ \ \ \ornament\par\nobreak}
    }}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 13\p@ 
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
\vspace*{0\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}
    \fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-10pt][c]{
    {\Large\bfseries\ornament\hfill#1\hfill\ornament\par\nobreak}
    }}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 25\p@ 
}}

\makeatother 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=10mm}
\geometry{right=10mm}
\geometry{top=10mm}
\geometry{bottom=15mm}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{enumitem}  
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{\Large\bfseries С\,О\,Д\,Е\,Р\,Ж\,А\,Н\,И\,Е}}  
\contentsmargin{0cm} 

\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{8pt}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\normalsize\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}  
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 

\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{3pt}\small\sffamily\amall} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\small\sffamily\small}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\small\sffamily\small} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\setlength\columnsep{10mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}[
  \chapter*{\contentsname   
    \@mkboth{%
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]
\@starttoc{toc}%
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother  

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\ULdepth = 0.16em 
\usepackage{pdf14}
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}

\doublehyphendemerits=1000000
\finalhyphendemerits=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
```

Result:
[image]

Variant macros for obtaining double frame:

```
\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\vspace*{0\p@}
 {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}
    \fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{% 
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-11pt][c]{
    {\Large\bfseries\ \ornament\ \ \chaptername\,\!\thechapter\hfill#1\ \ \ornament\ \par\nobreak}
    }}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 13\p@ 
 }}

 \def\@makeschapterhead#1{
 \vspace*{0\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}
    \fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{% 
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-11pt][c]{
    {\Large\bfseries\ \ornament\hfill#1\hfill\ornament\ \par\nobreak}
    }}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 25\p@ 
 }}

\makeatother
```

Result:
[image]

But the package shorttoc not friends with a decorative design --- elements move away to the side. To use shorttoc you have to remove them:

```
\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\vspace*{0\p@}
 {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}
    \fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-10pt][c]{
   {\Large\bfseries\chaptername\,\!\thechapter\hfill#1\par\nobreak}
    }}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 13\p@ 
 }}

 \def\@makeschapterhead#1{
 \vspace*{0\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2.0mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}
    \fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-10pt][c]{
    {\Large\bfseries\hfill#1\hfill\par\nobreak}
    }}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 25\p@ 
 }}

\makeatother
```

Here's what happened:
[image]

There is a choice: or decorative elements, or \shorttoc.

P.S. A macro from my question is also compiled with this corrected preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{0\p@}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7mm}\noindent\fbox{%
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{2.0mm}%
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
   \framebox[\textwidth-11pt][c]{\hspace*{0.25\parindent}\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase
{\ornament\ \ \@chapapp  \thechapter\hfill#1\ \ \ornament}\hspace*{0.25\parindent}}}
\par\nobreak
\vskip 10\p@}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{0\p@}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7mm}\noindent\fbox{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-11pt][c]{\hspace*{0.25\parindent}\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase
{\ornament\hfill#1\hfill\ornament}\hspace*{0.25\parindent}}}
\par\nobreak
\vskip 10\p@}
\makeatother
```

The result of the compilation:
[image]

P.P.S. Managed to solve the problem with a decorative design \shorttoc. For this I added to the preamble package etoolbox:

```
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

And where there should be shorttoc:

```
\begin{document}
\titlepage

\makeatletter
{\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\vskip 0em \@plus\p@}{}{}
{\errmessage{paching \string\l@chapter fail}}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\addvspace{0em \@plus\p@}}{}{}
{\errmessage{paching \string\l@chapter fail}}
\shorttoc{Краткое содержание}{0}}
\makeatother
```

The result of these actions:
[image]

The question is settled.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy, you solved a problem I had been struggling with for several days! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for this document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,small, openany,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{cmap}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{cite,float,textcomp,setspace}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{paratype}

\usepackage{ArtNouv}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\ArtNouvfamily{}} 
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage[pdflatex]{graphicx,xcolor}
\graphicspath{{grafika/}} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\redstar}{$\textcolor[rgb]{.87,0,0}{\bigstar}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-6pt]{79}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,symmetry=v,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-6pt]{79}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{0\p@}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7mm}\noindent\fbox{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-13.0pt][c]{\hspace*
{0.25\parindent}\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase
    {\lquercus\redstar\rquercus~~\@chapapp  \thechapter\hfill#1~~\lquercus\redstar\rquercus}\hspace*{0.25\parindent}}}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@}
\makeatother
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\geometry{left=10mm}
\geometry{right=10mm}
\geometry{top=15mm}
\geometry{bottom=15mm}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{nolistsep} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{0pt} % for shorttoc
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{\large\bf Подробное содержание}}  
\contentsmargin{0cm} 

\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{8pt}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\normalsize\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}  
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 

\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{3pt}\small\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\small\sffamily\small}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\small\sffamily\small} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5cm}} 
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\null\hfill\textbf{\large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\setlength\columnsep{10mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}[
\section*{\centering\large\contentsname   
    \@mkboth{
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]
\@starttoc{toc}
\end{multicols}}
\makeatother  

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\ULdepth = 0.16em 
\usepackage{pdf14}
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\doublehyphendemerits=1000000
\finalhyphendemerits=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\textsection~}
\shorttoc{\centerline{\large{\bfseries{Краткое содержание}}}}{0}

\chapter{С чего начать\ldots} % this \chapter should be \chapter*
\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent =0pt]{B}{э}том документе (my text)

\chapter{Первые блюда}
\noindent                    % minitoc two columns
\makebox[1.01\textwidth]{
{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-7\mboxsep-3\mboxrule\relax}
\centering
\setlength\columnsep{10mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\end{multicols}\\
\phantom{123}\\
\end{minipage}}
}

\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent =0pt]{P}{а}ньше я (my text)
\phantom{\lipsum[1]}
\vspace{-7mm}
\section{1}
\subsection{1.1}
(my text)

\chapter{2} 
\noindent     % minitoc one column 
\makebox[1.01\textwidth]{
{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-7\mboxsep-3\mboxrule\relax}
\centering
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\\
\phantom{123}\\
\end{minipage}}
}

\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent =0pt]{O}{б} этой (my text)
\phantom{\lipsum[5]}
\vspace{-7mm}
\section1 \subsection1 \subsubsection1 (my text)
...
\chapter{10}
\clearpage  
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

The document compiles, but how to make the design \chapter, the \tableofcontents and \shorttoc as well as the chapterhead in \chapter?.. I am unfortunately only a user and not a developer.

Texmaker 5.02, TeXLive2017 (updated) Slackware 14.2.

Answer (score 0):

Another option of decoration of the chapterhead:

```
\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\vspace*{17\p@}
{\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \mbox \textwidth{
    \centering {
    {\Large\bfseries\ \ \ \ornament\ \ 
\chaptername\,\!\thechapter\hfill#1\ \ \ornament\ \ \ \ \  \ \par\nobreak}
    } }
    \vspace{-47\p@}
    {\centering 
\includegraphics[width=190mm,height=25mm]{glawram7}  }
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 17\p@ 
 }}

 \def\@makeschapterhead#1{
 \vspace*{17\p@}
 {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
    \mbox \textwidth{
    \centering {
    {\Large\bfseries\ \ \ \ornament\hfill#1\hfill\ornament\ \ \ \ \  \ \par\nobreak}
  } }
    \vspace{-47\p@}
    {\centering \includegraphics[width=190mm,height=25mm]{glawram7}  }
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 17\p@ 
 }}

\makeatother
```

Also replaced the star with a Celtic knot:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\redstar}{\includegraphics[width=5.5mm]{uzel38}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-8pt]{79}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rquercus}{\pgfornament[height=0.7cm,symmetry=v,color=green!45!black,ydelta=-8pt]{79}}
\renewcommand{\ornament}{\lquercus\redstar\rquercus}
```

My result:
[image]

The decorative frame and Celtic knot are created in the Knotter program.
https://knotter.mattbas.org/Knotter

Sorry for the extra answer: it may be useful to someone.