# How to obtain effect of \fcolorbox using \@makechapterhead internal code

Tags: sectioning, color, chapters

The question I am asking has been influenced by the partial solutions I have found so far. It could be the wrong question to ask if there is a much easier way. Anyway, I need to put chapter titles inside a gray box. I was able to do this on the book title page using `\fcolorbox`, but have not been able to get the same effect with the chapters. I tried the titlesec package but found it difficult to understand the documentation. I also looked at the memoir package and was impressed by its length. Unfortunately I can't dedicate a few weeks to studying it and understanding it right now.

Then in the first answer at [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62516/how-to-suppress-chapter-in-chapter-while-keeping-numbering) I found a way to dig under the bonnet that seemed promising. Werner provided enough explanation for me to understand the way he used `\@makechapterhead` and to start customising the code to get what I need. However, I have no idea how to merge that code with the `\fcolorbox` command to obtain the same effect for the chapters. I realise that these are two different levels of coding, one is package-based, the other is internal. I looked in the color package but the internal code in there is kind of scary so I stopped trying. Here is my test code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{verylightgray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\usepackage[left=2cm, top=4cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}.\ \ }

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{50\p@}
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \fi
      \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
%       \vskip 40\p@
    \clearpage
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8pt}
\fcolorbox{black}{verylightgray}{
\parbox{15cm}
{\begin{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{\huge Book Title}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}}}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Objectives and Motivation}
\end{document}
```

As a sub-question which seems too small to ask as a separate question, on the last page you can see that the chapter label shows up right before the section number. Is it possible to change "A. .1 " to simply "1. "? You can ignore the default header and page numbers, they are just showing up in this test code but not in the real document. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Dmitriy who showed exactly what I was looking for, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419586/design-chapter-toc-and-shorttoc-memoir?rq=1).

I did give Memoir a try, but unfortunately I could not get it to work.

Adapting Dmitriy's answer to my problem I got this code to work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{verylightgray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\usepackage[left=2cm, top=4cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\vspace*{5cm}
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \fcolorbox{black}{verylightgray}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{10mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth][c]{
    \Large\bfseries \thechapter.\quad  #1\par\nobreak
    }}
    \par\nobreak
    \clearpage
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8pt}
\fcolorbox{black}{verylightgray}{
\parbox{15cm}
{\begin{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{\huge Book Title}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}
}}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Objectives and Motivation}
\end{document}
```